# How can I force homebrew to recompile?

Tags: homebrew

I'm trying to install wxWidgets on Mac OS X 10.9. It's already installed, but I'm having the problem described [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/23666). Someone suggested to add `ENV.append_to_cflags "-stdlib=libc++"`. I did, but I'm not able to recompile the code.

```
$ brew install wxmac
Warning: wxmac-3.0.0 already installed
$ brew edit wxmac
=> ok, modifications done, now I want to recompile and reinstall
$ brew uninstall wxmac
Uninstalling /usr/local/Cellar/wxmac/3.0.0...
$ brew install wxmac
==> Downloading https://downloads.sf.net/project/machomebrew/Bottles/wxmac-    3.0.0.mavericks.bottle.2.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/wxmac-3.0.0.mavericks.bottle.2.tar.gz
==> Pouring wxmac-3.0.0.mavericks.bottle.2.tar.gz
  /usr/local/Cellar/wxmac/3.0.0: 775 files, 41M
```

How can I force homebrew to recompile?

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Homebrew is installing wxmac in bottle form (a pre-compiled binary of wxmac). To build from source, add the `--build-from-source` flag when calling `brew install`:

```
$ brew install --build-from-source wxmac
```

Comment: Use `brew reinstall` to reinstall.

Answer (score 22):

To rebuild all installed FORMULAE from source:

```
$ brew list | xargs brew reinstall --build-from-source
```

Comment: Warning: Calling `brew list` to only list formulae is deprecated! Use `brew list --formula` instead.